# Blackberry code signing problem with Eclipse Helios and Galileo

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, signing

When i click Sign With Signature Tool,it ask me for password.At the bottom i can see `"Packaging Projects 99%"` it never completes, it keeps on processing. At the console i can see "Packaging project `BlackBerryMapsDemo`

> C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.7.0_4.7.0.57\components\bin\rapc.exe -convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\4.7.0\BlackBerryMapsDemo deliverables\Standard\4.7.0\BlackBerryMapsDemo.rapc -sourceroot=C:\workspace\BlackBerryMapsDemo\src;C:\workspace\BlackBerryMapsDemo\res -import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.7.0_4.7.0.57\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\workspace\BlackBerryMapsDemo\bin

`Packaging project BlackBerryMapsDemo succeeded (took 1.859 seconds)`

Signing files:
`[C:\workspace\BlackBerryMapsDemo\deliverables\Standard\4.7.0\BlackBerryMapsDemo.cod]"`

**It keeps of signing but never completes signing.** What is the problem here.If anyone can help me,i will be really grateful.

Comment: Anyone please help,i really want it badly,thnx in advance

Comment: Also when i click details,i can see one bar "Packaging Projects..."which is almost 99% complete,below that another bar is dere "Packing Project...:(Blocked:The user operation is waiting for background work to complete)"and is Lock sign is dere before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if BBDevMgr is running in Task Manager (I assume your using Windows). If its running, kill the process. I have seen this when trying to run the emulator it get stuck packaging the project, so could be same/related issue when you packaging for release.

Answer (score 1):

Quote: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Cannot-completely-sign-files-Error-Packaging-Projects-99/td-p/1640957

maybe the signing server was not responding in time?
check
isthesigningserverdown.com
and retry signing.